# How to member pass a function, which has another member function as an argument, to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a member function that takes another member function as an argument, which works normally when executed directly on the main thread. However, when trying to run this function in a separate thread, I get the following error on g++:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/thread:43,
                 from teste.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&); _Args = {Shell*&, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
teste.cpp:46:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:130:72: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  130 |                                       typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:130:72: note: ‘std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> >’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:203:13:   required from ‘struct std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> > >’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:143:29:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&); _Args = {Shell*&, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’
teste.cpp:46:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:252:11: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> >::__result<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> >’
  252 |           _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:256:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> >::__result<std::tuple<void (Shell::*)(void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria&), Shell*, void (Memoria::*)(), Memoria> >’
  256 |         operator()()
      |         ^~~~~~~~
```

The error happens in this example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Memoria {
 public:
  void imprimir() {
    cout << "printed" << endl;
  };
};

class Kernel {
 public:
  Memoria* memoria = new Memoria();
};

class Escalonador {
 public:
  Kernel* kernel = new Kernel();
};

class Shell {
 public:
  bool         loop        = true;
  Escalonador* escalonador = new Escalonador();
  template <class C>
  void function1(void (C::*function)(), C& c) {
    while (loop == true) {
      (c.*function)();
      usleep(500000);
    }
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  Shell* shell = new Shell();
  //Works
  //   shell->function1(&Memoria::imprimir,
  //                    *shell->escalonador->kernel->memoria);

  // not works
  thread t     = thread(&Shell::function1<Memoria>,
                    shell,
                    &Memoria::imprimir,
                    *shell->escalonador->kernel->memoria);
  cin.get();
  shell->loop = false;
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid raw owning pointers. smart pointers (or even directly no pointer at all here) would be better.

Comment: `std::thread` takes it's arguments by value. You can't pass a reference to it like that. Use `std::ref` or pass a pointer to a `Memoria` instead.

Comment: @super It was just that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @super tip, use std::ref()

```
t = thread(&Shell::function1<Memoria>,
                 this,
                 &Memoria::imprimir,
                 ref(*escalonador->kernel->memoria));
```